# python 3.5 in mod_wsgi apache

Tags: python, apache

Hi I am having problem on my apache server where I want my python version to be 3.5.1 but is running on 3.2.3. I am trying to compile the python 3.5 version on mod_wsgi.so however I get this as a response

```
/usr/local/opt/python-3.5.1/lib/libpython3.5m.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
```

Please take note that I the server is a debian wheezy on an apache 2.2 version